# Swift ui how to align VStack in start

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am using background image on VStack and i need to show the content from start means from .leading.

My code

```
struct HomeView: View {
    
    private var threeColumnGrid = [GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 0), GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 0), GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 0), GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 0)]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                
                ZStack {
                    Image("frontcard")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                }
                .frame(width: .infinity, height: 230)
                .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                
                VStack (alignment: .leading){
                    Text("Company Name")
                        .font(.system(size: 13))
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    
                    Text("Abdul Umaiz Khan")
                        .font(.system(size: 12))
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                    
                    HStack{
                        Text("Policy No : ").font(.system(size: 11)) + Text("60021").font(.system(size: 11)).fontWeight(.bold)
                        
                        Text("Class : ").font(.system(size: 11)) + Text("0002").font(.system(size: 11)).fontWeight(.bold)
                        
                        Text("Cert No : ").font(.system(size: 11)) + Text("383").font(.system(size: 11)).fontWeight(.bold)
                        
                        Text("Age : ").font(.system(size: 11)) + Text("23").font(.system(size: 11)).fontWeight(.bold)
         
                    }
                    HStack{
                        
                        Text("Cnic : ").font(.system(size: 11)) + Text("42201-5223212-3").font(.system(size: 11)).fontWeight(.bold)
                        
                        Text("Userid : ").font(.system(size: 11)) + Text("2015-ABCA-3").font(.system(size: 11)).fontWeight(.bold)
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                    Spacer()
   
                }
                .frame(width: .infinity, height: 230)
                .background(Image("backcard")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                )
                
                Spacer()
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("Company Name")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
     
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

In image there is gap in start I have marked it I need to show company name from start of image mean leading of VStack.

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes from the images scaling to fit a specific height.
Here is a solution without images.

Also note that you can use the `.font` modifiers on the whole `HStack`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                
                Color.blue
                    .cornerRadius(15)
                    .frame(height: 230)
                
                ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                    Color.gray.opacity(0.5)
                        .cornerRadius(15)
                        .frame(height: 230)
                    
                    VStack (alignment: .leading){
                        Text("Company Name")
                            .font(.system(size: 13))
                            .bold()
                        
                        Text("Abdul Umaiz Khan")
                            .font(.system(size: 12))
                            .bold()

                        HStack {
                            Text("Policy No : ") + Text("60021").bold()
                            Text("Class : ") + Text("0002").bold()
                            Text("Cert No : ") + Text("383").bold()
                            Text("Age : ") + Text("23").bold()
                        }
                        .font(.system(size: 11))
                        
                        HStack {
                            Text("Cnic : ") + Text("42201-5223212-3").bold()
                            Text("Userid : ") + Text("2015-ABCA-3").bold()
                        }
                        .font(.system(size: 11))

                        Spacer()
                        
                    }
                    .padding(8)
                }
                .frame(height: 230)
                
                Spacer()
                
            }
            .padding()
            
            .navigationTitle("Company Name")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default SwiftUI layouts views in center of the frame, but usually the frame is the same size as the view inside. In your case when you set `.frame(width: .infinity, height: 230)` you made your frame bigger then the containing view. Setting `.frame(width: .infinity, height: 230, alignment: .leading)` should do the trick.

Comment: I tried this but not working

Comment: You should be using maxWidth instead                                    ```.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading).frame( height: 230)```

Answer (score 0):

Place the root VStack inside a new HStack and write Spacer() at the end of new HStack.